# Find first empty row and scroll to it, Lastrow not working due to formulas

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to auto scroll to the first row after a given row number that has column A empty unloading the sheet (This Google Sheets)

the following formula works but scrolls past the last empty row as I assume if a row has formulas that add a blank in a cell it is counting them as not empty

```
 function onOpen(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetname = ss.getSheets()[0].getName();
 // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheetname = "+sheetname)
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
 var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1);
 sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

So I have tried modifying thus, but it doesn't scroll down

```
function onOpen(){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheetname = ss.getSheets()[0].getName();
 // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheetname = "+sheetname)
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
 var lastRow = sheet.getRange('A7:A').getLastRow() + 1;
 var range = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1);
 sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

column A is empty at row 600 say but the sheet doesn't scroll on loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, instead of the build-in `.lastRow()` method,

you can instead use `.findIndex()` with `.reverse()` and `.length` methods to find the last non-empty row number of a column.

```js
function onOpen(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetname = ss.getSheets()[0].getName();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheetname = "+sheetname)
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  const values = sheet.getRange('A7:A').getValues();
  const lastRow = values.length - (values.reverse().findIndex(row => !!row[0]));
  const range = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

But, if you are looking for `the first empty row`, you may consider to change the `lastRow` variable:

```js
function onOpen(){
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetname = ss.getSheets()[0].getName();
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: sheetname = "+sheetname)
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);
  const values = sheet.getRange('A7:A').getValues();
  // const lastRow = values.length - (values.reverse().findIndex(row => !!row[0]));
    const firstEmptyRow = values.findIndex(row => !row[0]) + 1;
  // const range = sheet.getRange(lastRow,1);
    const range = sheet.getRange(firstEmptyRow,1);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
}
```

By the way, declare variables with `const` whenever you could, and `let` when you couldn't, is a better practice than using `var` in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you, I have used the "first empty row" from the above with one change const firstEmptyRow = values.findIndex(row => !row[0]) + 1; I need to change the +1 to + 7 on the end.

Comment: Be aware that this will not give the correct result when the last value in column `A` is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the last row that has visible content with the `getLastRow_()` utility function attached below. Use it like this:

```js
  const lastRow = getLastRow_(sheet, 1);
  const range = sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1);
  sheet.setActiveRange(range);
```

You will need to paste the function code in your script project:

```js
/**
* Gets the position of the last row that has visible content in a column of the sheet.
* When column is undefined, returns the last row that has visible content in any column.
*
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet Optional. A sheet in a spreadsheet. Defaults to the active sheet.
* @param {SpreadsheetApp.Range} column Optional. The 1-indexed position of a column in the sheet, or a SpreadsheetApp.Range object that covers the columns where to find the last row with visible content, or an A1 type text string such as 'A:A' or 'A:B'.
* @return {Number} The 1-indexed row number of the last row that has visible content.
*/
function getLastRow_(sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(), column) {
  // version 1.6, written by --Hyde, 18 March 2023
  const values = (
    typeof column === 'number'
      ? sheet.getRange(1, column, sheet.getLastRow() || 1, 1)
      : typeof column === 'string'
        ? sheet.getRange(column)
        : column
          ? sheet.getRange(1, column.getColumn(), sheet.getLastRow(), column.getWidth())
          : sheet.getDataRange()
  ).getDisplayValues();
  let row = values.length - 1;
  while (row && !values[row].join('')) row--;
  return row + 1;
}
```